# How do I center these buttons

Tags: jquery, css

I have two functions in my jQuery which manage two buttons and then display them. What I want is for the buttons to be displayed in the center, but `align=center` doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do this in my jQuery code?

jQuery code below:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

    var $answer = $("<table class='answer'></table>");

    $('.allBtns:first-child').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $allBtnsClass = '';

        $allBtnsClass = $("<input class='allBtns btnsAll' type='button' style='display: inline-block;' value='Select All Answers' onClick='selectAll(this);' />")
            .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
            .attr('value', $this.val())
            .attr('class', $this.attr('class'));
        }

        $answer.append($allBtnsClass);
    });

    $('.allRemoveBtns:first-child').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $removeBtnsClass = '';

        $removeBtnsClass = $("<input class='allRemoveBtns btnsRemove' type='button' style='display: inline-block;' value='Remove All Answers' onClick='removeAll(this);' />")
            .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
            .attr('value', $this.val())
            .attr('class', $this.attr('class'));
        }

        $answer.append($removeBtnsClass);
    });

    $tr.append($answer);   
}
```

Comment: You have some extra `}`s in your code that I noticed when reindenting.  Are you sure your code is even running?

Comment: yeh they are unused, in `.each` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is your only issue, but you are placing your buttons in a `table`; tables should not directly contain `input` elements.  I don't think you need a table anyway.  If you make your container element a `div` (say, with the class `answers`), you can just have this style in your stylesheet:

```
.answers { text-align: center; }
```

Then, if you stop setting `display: inline-block` on your `input` buttons, they should display inline by default, and then the `text-align: center` of the container should take care of centering them.

Your JavaScript also contains too many `}`s.  They are only needed when pairing with `{`s.

I hope that helps.